# Remove date from text file with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a question about removing `date` and `time` from a text file with `notepad++`.

I tried with this RegEx but still not working

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}   \d{2}:\d{2}
```

The dates are like that:

```
04-21-1991  9:09    
04-21-1991  9:09    
04-21-1991  17:08   
04-21-1991  17:08   
04-22-1991  7:35    
04-22-1991  7:35    
04-22-1991  13:40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{2} means exactly 2

You should try this:

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}  \d{1,2}:\d{2}
```

Comment: its can't find the text

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes in your regex, it looks like.  The first is that the regex is looking for one more space than exists in the data.  The second is that you're looking for "exactly two digits" for the hour, you want "one or two."

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}  \d{1,2}:\d{2}
```

http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: not actualy that a tab space and not 3 spaces this is not working too

Comment: Try using `\s` instead then.  `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}`  This is also why I included a link to regexpal.com, as it is very good at helping solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: yes in the regexpal its working but in the notpad++ notworking 
ill copy the text and past it again to remove that space and it will work 
tank you very much for your help